# How can I declare this SQL table with a calculated field?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
create table Son
(
    ID int primary key identity(1,1),
    DateOfBirth datetime,
    constraint Age check (datediff(year,DateOfBirth,GetDate())>= 0),
    Name nvarchar(50) not null check (len(Name) >= 8) default('Sergio')
)
```

Right now I'm just checking it he Age column is bigger than 0, how can I declare the table if the Age column is meant to be calculated?

Comment: If age is calculated why do you need a constraint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can introduce a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE Son (
    ID int primary key identity(1,1),
    DateOfBirth datetime,
    Age as DATEDIFF(year,DateOfBirth,GetDate()) - CASE WHEN DATEPART(month,DateOfBirth) > DATEPART(month,GetDate()) THEN 1 WHEN DATEPART(month,DateOfBirth) = DATEPART(month,GetDate()) And DATEPART(day,DateOfBirth) > DATEPART(day,GetDate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
/* Other columns */
)
```

I think that formula's right - DATEDIFF simple measures boundary transitions (31st Dec -> 1st Jan), so you need to compare months and days also, otherwise someone born on 31st Dec is 1 year old a day later.

Comment: +1: in this case, if you insisted on a constraint, I'd put it on `DateOfBirth` since it's the only component in the calculation and doesn't change by itself like `Age`

Answer (score 0):

I would start by creating a function to calculate the age. This gives you something that is reusable on other tables as well as being able to be used in scenarios where you might want to calculate a persons age on a specific date. For example, I'm looking to throw a party later this year, and I want to know everyone that will be of legal age on that date to send them an invitation.

Then create your table and add the calculated column that references that function. Add the check constraint for the age and the length of the Given Name, etc.

You should be wary though, that by using a function, you cannot alter this function without dropping the references from the table (i.e. the computed column).

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.sfn_GetAge (@BirthDate datetime, @CalcDate datetime)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @theAge INT

    IF Month(@CalcDate) > Month(@BirthDate ) 
        SELECT @theAge= (Year(@CalcDate) - Year(@BirthDate ))

    ELSE IF Month(@CalcDate) < Month(@BirthDate ) 
        SELECT @theAge= ((Year(@CalcDate) - Year(@BirthDate )) - 1)

    ELSE IF Day(@CalcDate) < Day(@BirthDate ) 
        SELECT @theAge= ((Year(@CalcDate) - Year(@BirthDate )) - 1)

    ELSE 
        SELECT @theAge= (Year(@CalcDate) - Year(@BirthDate ))

    RETURN @theAge

END
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Son](
    [ID] INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    [GivenName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Surname] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Age]  AS ([dbo].[sfn_GetAge]([DateOfBirth],getdate()))
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Son] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Son_GivenName]  DEFAULT (N'Sergio') FOR [GivenName]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Son]  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_Son_Age] CHECK (([dbo].[sfn_GetAge]([DateOfBirth],getdate())>=(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Son] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_Son_Age]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Son]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Son_GivenName] CHECK  ((len([GivenName])>=(8)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Son] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_Son_GivenName]
GO
```